# PersistenceException when running SynchronizeMappings

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, openjpa

I have eclipse java project using apache `openJPA`. Has eclipse got some kind of cache need to be clean?

I had one class , UsaState ...mapped to `USA_STATE` table. I have removed it from database, from `persistence.xml`, from project, from references in mappings ...there are no other referenced project and I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main"  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException:
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
    near 'TYPE = innodb' at line 1 {stmnt 7860099
        CREATE TABLE USA_STATE (
            ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            NAME VARCHAR(255),
            ADDRESS BIGINT,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID)
        ) TYPE = innodb
    } [code=1064, state=42000]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:553)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:453)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:189)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:18)
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: You have
    an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE =
    innodb' at line 1 {stmnt 7860099
        CREATE TABLE USA_STATE (
            ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            NAME VARCHAR(255),
            ADDRESS BIGINT,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID)
        ) TYPE = innodb
    } [code=1064, state=42000]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:57)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingStatement.executeUpdate(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:762)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:114)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.executeSQL(SchemaTool.java:1191)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.createTable(SchemaTool.java:949)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.add(SchemaTool.java:526)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.add(SchemaTool.java:344)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.run(SchemaTool.java:321)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:501)
    ... 9 more
```

Where could be the problem? In what way could persistence remember that table or entity?
Is there neccesary some clean? I have already cleaned project some times...

Thanks

Comment: After formatting, it looks like a [syntax error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

Comment: The question is nonsensical, but the posted stack is a valid problem that has already been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Please move to a newer version of JPA >= 2.0.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1530

Comment: I haave switched to 2.1.1 ...Now there is some problem with runtime enhancement , I am solving it , but ....how it was possible that EntityManagerFactory or waht remembered class already doesn't exist in project? thanks anyway

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question, it doesn't make any sense to me?

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your database or execute command `flush tables`.